# Preserve Scroll Position When Pushing ViewController In Code in a Storyboard App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have a storyboard app that has a few view controller that need to get pushed on the navigation stack programmatically, instead of with segues. I'm using the following code to do it:

```
POCollectionViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"categoryView"];
POCategory* destination = (POCategory*)self.collections[indexPath.row];
[vc setShowingCollection:destination];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

My problem is that when I use segues to push view controllers and I press the 'back' button, the scroll position is preserved, but when I use the above code and press the 'back' button, my previous view controller appears with the scroll bar at the top.

Is it re-instantiating a view controller that is supposed to be already on the navigation stack? How can I preserve the scroll position?

**EDIT** 
Code for `setShowingCollection:`

```
-(void)setShowingCollection:(POCategory*)collection
{
    self->showingCollection = collection;
    self.title = collection.name;

    self.HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    self.HUD.delegate = self;
    [self.HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(buildDisplayItems) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
```

The `buildDisplayItems` method fetches a bunch of the data from the server based on the showing collection's ID.

Comment: Do you ever set the scroll position from code? Is this a custom back button (action method)?

Comment: No to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not popping the controller correctly, your are not poping to the pushed controller, but popping to a newest controller. How you are doing the pop controller in your back button ?

you should do like this :

> [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I just push one VC programmatically, using `pushViewController:animated:` and I leave the back button and the pop action to the navigation controller.

Comment: The problem can be in the setShowingCollection method. What are you doing in this method ? can you show the code ?

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought is if you must instantiate a new controller for every "segue" you will have to save the scroll position and when you reload the view cause the the uiscrollview to scroll.

Something like this saved in a property should do the trick:

```
CGRect scrolledRect = CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y, scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height);
```

Then when you reload:

```
 [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:scrolledRect animated:NO];
```

Comment: Isn't the navigation controller supposed to keep the past view controllers on its stack the way they are? I instantiate a new VC and push it. But for going back nothing is done in code, it's just the navigation controller doing its job.